# Use http path to set active tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this example of vertical tabs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `vertical-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `vertical-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function VerticalTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'background.paper', display: 'flex', height: 224 }}
    >
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        <Tab label="Item Four" {...a11yProps(3)} />
        <Tab label="Item Five" {...a11yProps(4)} />
        <Tab label="Item Six" {...a11yProps(5)} />
        <Tab label="Item Seven" {...a11yProps(6)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
        Item Four
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
        Item Five
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={5}>
        Item Six
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={6}>
        Item Seven
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/verticaltabs-material-demo-forked-cewtk?file=/demo.tsx

Is it possible to use url link in order to set active tab? For example:

```
http://localhost/tabs/one -> set tab 1 as active 
http://localhost/tabs/three -> set tab 3 as active
```

I found this example https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting but it's not looking appropriate for me because I want to keep using Tabs component. Is there some other solution with Tabs component?

Comment: You can use react router with the tabs component by using the history and location from the react router.

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: Updating your codesandbox example with url support. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your sandbox example. Changes are made in both files. First lets discuss the changes in `demo.tsx`

**Demo.tsx**

first, I've imported a couple of hooks from the `react-router-dom`

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Added a util function to get the active tab based on the url path.

```
function getNumber(location: string) {
  const pathname = location.split("/")[2];
  if (!pathname) return 0;
  else {
    switch (pathname) {
      case "two":
        return 1;
      case "three":
        return 2;
      case "four":
        return 3;

      default:
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then state and hooks initialization. The initial state will also check for the url and make the relevant tab active based on the url parameter on the component mount.

```
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(getNumber(location?.pathname));
```

The `handleChange` function, which updates the tab based on the index is changed. Instead of updating state value for the tab, it now pushes the new url based on the tab index.

```
const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
history.push(
  `/${
    newValue === 1
      ? "tabs/two"
      : newValue === 2
      ? "tabs/three"
      : newValue === 3
      ? "tabs/four"
      : "tabs/one"
    }`
  );
};
```

Since in the above `handleChange` function the `value` is not being updated and that is essentially controlling the active tab, I moved that code to a `useEffect` hook, with a dependency on the `location` object. Whenever the location changes, this will automatically update the relevant tab. The state change is moved to the `useEffect` to handle the scenario, when the user presses the back button to go back to the previous tab, we can update the `value` state based on the `location` change.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setValue(getNumber(location?.pathname));
}, [location]);
```

**changes in the `Index.tsx`**

Imported some components from the `react-router-dom` to manage the url navigation.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Than move the whole app code inside the `Router`, so, all the components have access to the router.

```
<Router>
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/tabs/:tab?" component={Demo} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Demo} />
    </Switch>
  </StyledEngineProvider>
</Router>
```

Here is the updated [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/verticaltabs-material-demo-forked-innes?file=/index.tsx:249-477).

Comment: Wrapping in with a useTabSelection hook of some sort would make it even cleaner. Great answer.